# In sails, how to handle "nulls" in a JSON field in a database?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, sails.js

Well say I have a database that has a schema like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mytable
(
    datacolumn json,
    id serial NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Clearly datacolumn *can* be null: null is even an important value of this.

Now in sails I have a datamodel defined as:

```
moduel.exports = {
  attributes: {
    datacolumn: {
      type: 'ref',
      columnType: 'json',
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  id: {
    type: 'number',
  },
}
```

This should work right? - Well it doesn't sails refuses to lift:

> Failed to lift app: userError: The attribute `datacolumn` on the `mytable` model contains invalid properties. The `allowNull` flag may not be used on attributes with type `json` or type `ref`.

I could of course just remove the line `allowNull`: but that would give lots of warnings that null is not a valid value (directly logged, and giving like 10 lines per warning). And I doubt it will correctly *insert* null values would it?

So how to handle above database schema?

Comment: There is a JSON Null value, maybe use this instead of a database null.

Comment: @JPMoresmau that woudl require updating the database model and other application, the sails application is (by far) not the only application using the database and datamodel.